# Parent child relation with One to One

Tags: database-design

We have a table called `Contracts` which has a lot of columns. Some columns are for employees, some columns are for managers, some columns are for locals and so on. Since the table is growing, that's why I wanna refactor it. I have the following options,

1. Keep one table `Contracts` for all columns.
2. Keep a separate table for each contract, `EmployeeContract`, `LocalContract`, `ManagerContract` and so on.
3. Keep one table `Contracts` for common columns and separate table for  `EmployeeContract`, `LocalContract`, `ManagerContract` and so on.

Is it fine to have a parent-child with one-to-one relations?

Update: I am looking whether it makes sense to have sub-class and super-class like features in tables. `Contracts` will be super-class(super table) and `EmployeeContract`, `LocalContract`, `ManagerContract` are sub-classes(or sub tables)?

Comment: Is the new table you describe going to be something like "ContractType", where the listed types are Employee, Local, Manager? In that case, there would be a one to many relationship as there can be more than 1 Employee, Local or Manager. If I've missed what you're asking please elaborate on the question and possibly give examples with data in your current table.

Comment: It sounds as though Employees, Locals, and Managers are subclasses of some kind of superclass of people who can have contracts.  If this is true, see if you can reword your question so as to take this into account.

Comment: Sql_Hacker and Walter, I updated the question.

Comment: @SQL_Hacker nice I have found a very good answer of you at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120176/representing-a-superclass-subclass-or-supertype-subtype-relationship-in-a-mysq